# MVC Razor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm iterating through my Model in javascript and I get a compilation error :
" The name 'i' does not exist in the current context"
alerting i is working ok. **How can I escape the Razor to get the i** please ?

```
for(i=0; i<@Model.Count();i++)
{
    //alert(i);
    alert(@Model.ElementAt(i).Description.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing javascript and Razor. Try only using javascript for the alert call.

```
@for(var i=0; i<@Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <text>
    alert("@Model.ElementAt(i).Description.ToString()");
    </text>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@model is something the server knows, and the value of 'i' is something the client knows. You would either need to recreate the array as a javascript array and use that instead of @model, or maybe use ajax instead and pass the value of `i` as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you just forgot to declare `i` in the `for` loop and properly declare it as C# syntax

```
@for(var i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++) {
  ...
}
```